# Flex3 Linechart points are too close to the edge

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, charts, linechart

I have a Flex3 LineChart component using an CircleItemRenderer and the datapoints are being cut off because they are too close to the edge.  Here's what it looks like:

http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/3850/chartx.png

As you can see, the circles on the left and right sides are being cut off.

How can I make the LineSeries area, plus the horizontal labels, narrower so it fits in the chart area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by setting the clipContent attribute in the chart tag to false.  I found this solution on [Amy's Flex Diary](http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2008/07/some-thoughts-on-charting.html).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to set the maximum and minimum values in your LinearAxis in the horizontalAxis object. Check the API for more information: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/LinearAxis.html

The Line Chart determines automatically these values to fill all the elements in the screen. You might want to change these values so the graph has some space at the sides.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the padding property on the horizontalAxis and verticalAxis child objects as well...

Answer (score 1):

[Adjust the mask](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&postId=13111&productId=2&loc=en_US) on the chart component.

Answer (score 1):

I got d solution.

1. create `creationComplete` event in LineChart
2. edit horizontalAxis's padding you want

   `e.target.horizontalAxis.padding = 0.2;`

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by changing the type from LineChart to ColumnChart.  I still had all of the same axis definitions including Line Series.  The results are the same Line graph, but more centered on the graph instead of touching the edges.  None of the other padding or gutters were what I was looking for.